# SQL auto counter in a table depending on another table

Tags: mysql

i have a project in JSF about a website for courses to be added and joined in , 
in my database i have these three tables (`course` , `student` , `student_has_course`)

- `course` has the columns of (`course_id`,`name`,`student_no`)
- `student` has the columns of (`student_id`,`name`,`surname`,`..`)
- `student_has_course` has the columns of (`id`,`course_id`,`student_id`)

`student_has_course` represent the relation between the students and the courses they are enrolled in, which is many to many, my problem here ..

i need a way to automatically increase `student_no` in the table courses for each course , depending on how many student_course relation it has .

if it could be done just by using MySql it would be great .. 
I've search many times , i found triggers and some Sql codes but it was not helpful that much,

Comment: I suggest you remove the `student_no` column from the `course` table and derive the value when you need it instead, e.g. for display. I don't recommend storing derived values in the database unless you're trying to solve a performance problem. If you're not using database triggers, I cannot think of a mechanism to "automatically" increment `student_no`: you could include the update in some sort of `registerStudent` method, but that's more "manual" than "automatic".

Comment: By the way, as worded this has nothing to do with JSF. I will remove the tag. It might arguably have something to do with JPA (dubious), but you haven't mentioned if you're using it.